# docker-compose: connection refused between containers, but service accessible from host

Tags: ruby, docker, redis, containers

TL;DR: How do I have to change my below `docker-compose.yml` in order to allow one container to use a service of another over a custom (non-standard) port?

I have a pretty common setup: containers for a web app (Padrino [Ruby]), Postgres, Redis, and a queueing framework (Sidekiq). The web app comes with its custom Dockerfile, the remaining services come either from standard images (Postgres, Redis), or mount the data from the web app (Sidekiq). They are ties together via the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: 'bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "9000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: 'bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -r ./config/boot.rb'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: my-postgres-user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my-postgres-pass
    ports:
      - '9001:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '9002:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

One key point to notice here is that I am exposing the containers services on *non-standard* ports (9000-9002).

If I start the setup with `docker-compose up`, the Redis and Postgres containers come up fine, but the containers for the web app and Sidekiq fail since they can't connect to Redis at `redis:9002`. Remarkably enough, the same setup *works* if I use 6379 (the standard Redis port) instead of 9002.

`docker ps` also looks fine afaik:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
9148566c2509        redis                   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   Less than a second ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:9002->6379/tcp             rubydockerpadrino_redis_1
e6d47321c939        postgres:9.5            "/docker-entrypoint.s"   Less than a second ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:9001->5432/tcp             rubydockerpadrino_postgres_1
```

What's even more confusing: I can access the Redis container *from the host* via `redis-cli -h localhost -p 9002 -n 0`, but the web app and Sidekiq containers fail to establish a connection.

I am using this docker version on MacOS:
`Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec, experimental`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I'd appreciate any hint how to get my setup running.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you bind ports like this `'9002:6379'` you're telling Docker to forward traffic from `localhost:9002` -> `redis:6379`. That's why this works from your host machine:

```
redis-cli -h localhost -p 9002 -n 0
```

However, when containers talk to each other, they are all connected to the same network by default (the Docker bridge *or* `docker0`). By default, containers can communicate with each other *freely* on this network, without needing any ports opened. Within this network, your `redis` container is listening for traffic on it's usual port (`6379`), host isn't involved at all. That's why your container to container communication works on `6379`.

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you so much for pointing me to the part (the port mapping and that it forwards the ports to the host, but not inter-container) I misunderstood until now. Now it works! :)

Comment: The mapping is useful for when you may have multiple containers that listen on the same port internally, and need to re-map on localhost. As each container is separate, that's no issue in container-to-container. There are also settings where you can turn off container-to-container communication, and also create other networks rather than the default to connect your containers to. Remember to accept the answer if it worked :)