# docker-compose: redis connection refused between containers

Tags: python, docker, redis, containers

I am trying to setup a docker-compose file that is intended to replace a single Docker container solution that runs several processes (RQ worker, RQ dashboard and a Flask application) with [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

The host system is a Debian 8 Linux and my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this (I deleted all other entries to reduce error sources):

```
version: '2'
  services:
    redis:
      image: redis:latest
    rq-worker1:
      build: .
      command: /usr/local/bin/rqworker boo-uploads
      depends_on:
        - redis
```

"rq-worker1" is a Python [RQ worker](http://python-rq.org/), trying to connect to redis via localhost and port 6379, but it fails to establish a connection:

```
redis_1       | 1:M 23 Dec 13:06:26.285 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
rq-worker1_1  | [2016-12-23 13:06] DEBUG: worker: Registering birth of worker d5cb16062fc0.1
rq-worker1_1  | Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
galileoqueue_rq-worker1_1 exited with code 1
```

The output of `docker ps` looks like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                      CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
36cac91670d2        redis:latest        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   14 minutes ago      Up About a minute   6379/tcp                galileoqueue_redis_1
```

I tried everything from running the RQ worker against the local IPs 0.0.0.0 / 127.0.0.1 and even localhost. Other solutions posted on Stackoverflow didn't work for me, too ([docker-compose: connection refused between containers, but service accessible from host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440415/docker-compose-connection-refused-between-containers-but-service-accessible-fr) e.g.).

And this is my `docker info` output:

```
Containers: 25
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 24
Images: 485
Server Version: 1.12.5
Storage Driver: aufs
  Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Dirs: 436
  Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: null bridge host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options:
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 13.61 GiB
Name: gp-pc-201
ID: LBGV:K26G:UXXI:BWRH:OYVE:OQTA:N7LQ:I4DV:BTNH:FZEW:7XDD:WOCU
```

Does anyone have an idea why the connect between the two containers doesn't work?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your code `localhost` from `rq-worker1` is `rq-worker1` itself, not `redis` and you can't reach `redis:6379` by connect to `localhost` from `rq-worker1`. But by default `redis` and `rq-worker1` are in the same [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and you can use service name as a domain name in that network.
It means, that you can connect to `redis` service from `rq-worker1` using `redis` as a domain name, for instance: `client.connect(("redis", 6379))`

You should replace `localhost` with `redis` in config of `rq-worker1`.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the connection error. I used the host parameter for all Python commands to connect to "redis" and it works perfectly.

Comment: I was having a similar problem, trying to access the redis-server from a django web service.  What solved the problem for me was to alter my docker-compose.yml file to expose port 6379 in my spec for the redis_db service (I used this instead of redis since that's also the image name) and then in my "web" service, I added "links: /n - redis_db"  (note the new line in there).  After that I was able to connect to redis from inside my web service.

Comment: The idea expressed here helped me in solving inter container communication issue with the error: 
Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address