# Docker container issue can't communicate

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I beginner in Docker, I write the simple docker-compose.yml file for run two service container first container for node app and another one for redis issue with my app server unable to connect with redis container here is my code:

```
version: '3'
services:
    redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        networks:
            - test
    app_server:
        image: app_server
        depends_on:
            - redis
        links:
           - redis
        ports:
            - "4004:4004"
        networks:
            - test
networks:
    test:
```

**Output:
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED**

Comment: The hostname of the Redis container is "redis", how are you trying to communicate?

Comment: I currently use  two containers  one container has app_server and another is redis but they are not communicating through a network

Comment: docker-compose sets a default network for you.

Comment: I want  to create custom network

Comment: How is the app server configured to reach redis? From the error it looks like it is using `localhost` or the loopback interface; try using the hostname `redis` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker-compose: redis connection refused between containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302791/docker-compose-redis-connection-refused-between-containers)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `webapp` is connecting to `127.0.0.1`/`localhost` instead of `redis`. So not a docker issue, but more of a programming issue within your web app. you could add environment variable in your webapp (something like `REDIS_HOST`) and then give that parameter in the compose-file. This of course requires your web application to read `redis` host from environment variable.

Example environment variable assignment in compose:

```
  webapp:
      image: my_web_app
      environment:
          - REDIS_HOST=redis
```

Again, this requires that your web app is actually utilizing `REDIS_HOST` environment variable in its code.

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1:6379` is connect to `current container localhost` not to redis container

With your docker-composer file. Now your connect to redis via redis container name. Becase docker-compose automatic create an docker bridge network - whic allow you call to another container via their name...
`docker inspect` to see redis container name - for example current redis container name is `redis_abc`, so you can connect to redis via `redis_abc:6379` Or more simple, just add `container_name: redis_server` to docker-compose file for certain container name..
https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/